# How to test whether any non-header cell in Excel file is bold or italic

Tags: c#, unit-testing, excel, named-ranges

We use an Excel sheet which contains some business logic (and so it is often edited by non-IT). Some C++ code is generated in VBA from the same sheet - silly, I know. I plan to write a bunch of unit tests against this worksheet, ensuring strict format for the benefit of all. For instance, things should be sorted alphabetically. I have not done this sort of work before; not even sure which library to use. To get my feet wet, I would like to find all cells which have font other than "automatic color, plain style, Arial, size 10" - e.g. red or bold or size 11, or ComicSans font. Then I want to check if those cells are "non-header" cells. The "header" cells are those which are part of known named ranges. For instance, if such cell does belong to a named range "XYZheaders", then it is Ok. If not, then I wish to report the coordinates of a cell (ideally as something human-readable like "D25" for every cell which has a problem, as well as indicate whether the problem is with color, font type, style, or size.

***EDIT:*** I just put bounty on this question because I am looking for a complete C# sample. Please do ask questions if you think that my question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution. I've tested it with some Excel 2007 files (.xlsx). The program can be built using VS 2010 (targeting .NET 4) with the following four references: Microsoft.CSharp, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, System and System.Core.

Using .NET 4 makes it a bit easier to work with Excel.

Anyway here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application excelapplication = null;
            Excel.Workbook workbook = null;

            try
            {
                excelapplication = new Excel.Application();
                workbook = excelapplication.Workbooks.Open(args[0]);
                var errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
                foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in workbook.Sheets)
                {
                    int rowCount = sheet.UsedRange.Cells.Rows.Count;
                    int colCount = sheet.UsedRange.Cells.Columns.Count;
                    var usedCells = sheet.UsedRange.Cells;

                    for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                        {
                            Excel.Range range = usedCells[i, j];
                            List<string> cellErrors;
                            if (HasNonDefaultFont(range, out cellErrors))
                            {
                                if (!IsHeaderCell(workbook, range))
                                {
                                    string cellDisplayTitle = String.Format("{0}!{1}", sheet.Name, range.Address);
                                    errors[cellDisplayTitle] = cellErrors;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ReportErrors(errors);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (workbook != null)
                    workbook.Close();
                if (excelapplication != null)
                    excelapplication.Quit();
            }
        }

        static bool HasNonDefaultFont(Excel.Range range, out List<string> differences)
        {
            differences = new List<string>();

            if (range.Font.Color != 0.0)
                differences.Add("Has font-color");

            if (range.Font.Bold)
                differences.Add("Is bold");

            if (range.Font.Italic)
                differences.Add("Is italic");

            if (range.Font.Underline != (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlUnderlineStyle.xlUnderlineStyleNone)
                differences.Add("Is underline");

            if (range.Font.Strikethrough)
                differences.Add("Is strikethrough");

            if (range.Font.Name != "Arial")
                differences.Add(String.Format("Font is {0}", range.Font.Name));

            if (range.Font.Size != 10)
                differences.Add(String.Format("Font size is {0}", range.Font.Size));

            return differences.Count != 0;
        }

        static bool IsHeaderCell(Excel.Workbook workbook, Excel.Range range)
        {
            // Look through workbook names:
            foreach (Excel.Name namedRange in workbook.Names)
            {
                if (range.Parent == namedRange.RefersToRange.Parent && range.Application.Intersect(range, namedRange.RefersToRange) != null)
                    return true;
            }

            // Look through worksheet-names.
            foreach (Excel.Name namedRange in range.Worksheet.Names)
            {
                if (range.Parent == namedRange.RefersToRange.Parent && range.Worksheet.Application.Intersect(range, namedRange.RefersToRange) != null)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        static void ReportErrors(Dictionary<string, List<string>> errors)
        {
            if (errors.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found the following errors:");
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-15} | Error", "Cell");
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kv in errors)
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-15} | {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value.Aggregate((e, s) => e + ", " + s));
        }
    }
}
```

The program assumes the name of an excel-file as its first argument. This file is opened and each cell is tested against different font-criteria. The cells with "non-default-font" is tested against the named ranged, and those that fall outside of these ranges are output to the console.

As usual some errorhandling should be added to the program - but hopefully this should get you started.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick, enjoy.  Keep in mind that putting in new Range Names will not trigger a recalc of a cell containing this function (so hit <kbd>F9</kbd> after creating range names).

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IsDataCellBoldOrItalic() As Boolean
    Dim rngName As Name
    Dim intersectRange As Name

    For Each rngName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If Not Intersect(rngName.RefersToRange, Application.ThisCell) Is Nothing Then
            IsDataCellBoldOrItalic = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    ''# Now we know we are not in a "header" cell
    IsDataCellBoldOrItalic = Application.ThisCell.Font.Bold Or Application.ThisCell.Font.Italic

End Function
```

Comment: Cool, this is plain `VB.Net` right? I suppose I can translate this into `C#` easily then.

Comment: @Hamish: looks like this is VBA that you would run from within the workbook.

Comment: Hm ... I suppose I could use that, but I prefer C# code which loads and analyzes an Excel file.

Comment: @Hamish: Oh, sorry I misunderstood that you wanted VBA. Yes, there aren't really any hidden tricks to convert to C#, except that a bunch of the properties you'd expect only exist as 'get_' methods. For example, you won't find a Workbook.Names property, but you'll find a Workbook.get_Names() method.

Comment: fyi: I put up a bounty for a complete answer as stated.